# Unable to set Local time zone in Terraform IAC on AWS Event Bridge rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-event-bridge

Terraform has aws_cloudwatch_event_target
see docs:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_event_target

I have a schedule pattern for a cron event to run currently in GMT time.

I want to edit this in IAC (Terraform) to be "Local Time Zone" instead. There is an option for it in the AWS console but I cannot find anyway to change this value in Terraform! Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Probably its only console thing, which converts it to UTC in the background.

Comment: That dropdown is used to show you the next 10 trigger dates either in GMT or in your time zone.  It is just an UI feature, it does not affect the cron expression. All Event Bridge events are using UTC time zones.